# Target -post-jar not executed when in imported build script

Tags: xml, netbeans, import, target, build.xml

I'm fairly new to netbeans and its build definition so what I'm trying to achieve may just not be possible ...

I'm developping several plugins using netbeans and I want all the jar files to be copied in a common directory after beeing generated.

I can do that with a `<target name="-post-jar">` block in every `build.xml` file, but as there will be more common things to do in the future I want to put the copy instructions in a common file that will be included in every `build.xml` file of every plugin.

Here is what I did :

I created a `movejar.xml` file in the directory where all my projects are located (`/home/xxx/dev/plugins`) with this content :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="movejar" default="default" basedir=".">
    <target name="-post-jar">
        <property name="mcp.destpath" value="/home/xxx/dev/plugins" />
        <echo message="Moving ${dist.jar} to ${mcp.destpath}" />
        <copy file="${dist.jar}" flatten="true" todir="${mcp.destpath}" />
    </target>
</project>
```

I then added an `import` instruction to `/home/xxx/dev/plugins/myplugin/build.xml` :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="myplugin" default="default" basedir=".">
    <description>Builds, tests, and runs the project myplugin.</description>
    <import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>
    <import file="../movejar.xml"/>
</project>
```

The import is fine because when I put a `<echo>foo</echo>` in `movejar.xml` (outside of the `target` section) it shows up in the compile log.

The problem is that the `-post-jar` target is not executed at compile time (jar generation is enabled in project properties of course), the echo don't show up in the compile log and the jar file is not copied, no errors either ...

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, nailed it, I'm a bit shameful I didn't try this before ...

Short version : `import` your stuff before netbeans' `import`.

When importing things then first definition kind of "locks" future definitions so anything defined in a previous `import` makes it impossible to override the definition in a later `import` ...

Netbeans automagically generate all possible `target` sections in `nbproject/build-impl.xml`, even empty ones, so everything you need to define must be imported beforehand (whereas adding a target section at the root of `build.xml` can be done after importing `build-impl.xml` without problem ...).